# Programming remote key Mitsubishi Colt 2007 1.3

Tags: obd-ii, mitsubishi, key, colt

I tried programming the remote key, but I can't get car in programming mode as is described in most YT video's by connecting pins 1 and 4 in OBD and pressing 6 times the emergency button. This should work with Mitsubishi, but it does not with Colt as it does not have pin 4 in OBD port (check added picture).

The usual Mitsubishi remote key programming:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=d8RjYVTjE7E

My OBD port:
[image]

So my question is how to get car in the programming mode?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Tried searching for Mitsubishi forums with Colt sub group then asking members for advice?

Comment: HandyHowie my question is how to get car in key programming mode?

Comment: In what way does it not have pin 4? No matter which corner I count from, I see an opening in the 4th position. The real question is "where is pin 1"?